# Get result of TCL exec command into array

Tags: tcl, exec

How to get the result of a tcl exec command into an array of strings where each item is a line of my exec output?

Example:

```
exec ls -la
```

How to capture that result into an array and print it in a foreach?

Comment: Note that in Tcl, a list is a random-access sequence, basically the same as an array in other languages only more dynamic. A Tcl array, OTOH, is an associative structure of variable names, similar to a hash or dictionary in other languages except that it isn't a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can I advise you to use list instead of array? If so...

```
set output [exec ls]
set output_list [split $output \n]
foreach line $output_list {
   puts $line
}
```

List is much more useful collection in this situation, because all you need is to store lines one by one. On the other hand, array in Tcl was made to store named collection (without order).

I can make it with array, but it would be ugly.

```
set output [exec ls]
set output_list [split $output \n]
set i 0
foreach line $output_list {
   set arr($i) $line
   incr i
}
foreach index [array names arr] {
    puts $arr($index)
}
```

As you can see, foreach for arrays can't guaranty order of records. For example I've got this

```
% foreach index [array names arr] {
    puts arr($index)
}
arr(8)
arr(4)
arr(0)
arr(10)
arr(9)
arr(5)
arr(1)
arr(6)
arr(2)
arr(7)
arr(3)
```

So if you want to work with array as it is ordered collection, you need to use counter.

```
for {set i 0} {$i < [array size arr]} {incr i} {
   puts $arr($i)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ruslan! How would it be that solution implemented with array?

Comment: Please check my answer. I've added solution with array, but it is ugly.